# TableView doesnt display data after View is changed

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, tableview

I have a problem. At the moment I'm polishing my app and debug it and so on. Something weird happened. Here is how it works: User enters data and gets to the TableView and the data gets displayed. Simple. But as soon as he switches to another view and then back to the TableView, the data is gone! The weird thing is that it didnt happen before. (I redid some codelines, maybe I changed something unknowingly). I have a hinch what it might be, but it would be weird because it worked before. The problem I think lies at the buttonTag line:

```
      - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

  // cell.image = selectedImage;
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia" size:14.0];

if (buttonTag == 9001) {    
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@  %@ %@,  %@.", [self.userData objectAtIndex:0], [self.userData objectAtIndex:1], [self.userData objectAtIndex:2], [self.userData objectAtIndex:3]];
    }
if (buttonTag == 9002) {    
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@, %@.", [self.userData objectAtIndex:0], [self.userData objectAtIndex:1], [self.userData objectAtIndex:2], [self.userData objectAtIndex:3]];
}
if (buttonTag == 9003) {    
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@  %@ %@,%@.", [self.userData objectAtIndex:0], [self.userData objectAtIndex:1], [self.userData objectAtIndex:2], [self.userData objectAtIndex:3]];
}


return cell;
```

}

Because he just displays the data when a particular button is pressed. If you change to the TableView without pressing one of those buttons (From a Tabbar e.g.) it doesnt show anything. My question is now: How can I tell the TableView to maintan the data from the last button pressed? (I was thinking NSUserDefaults?)

Here is another ViewController, the one from where you get to the TableView:

```
  - (IBAction)savePressed:(id)sender

{
if (buttonTag == 9001) {
     button.tag = 9001;
NSUserDefaults *savetext = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[savetext setObject:Antwort.text forKey:@"hallo"];
[savetext setObject:Antwort2.text forKey:@"hallo2"];
[savetext setObject:Antwort3.text forKey:@"hallo3"];
UIButton *buttonPressed = (UIButton *)sender;
TV *second =[[TV alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
second.buttonTag  = buttonPressed.tag; 
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:second animated:YES];

}
if (buttonTag == 9002) {
     button.tag = 9002;
    NSUserDefaults *savetext = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [savetext setObject:Antwort.text forKey:@"hallo"];
    [savetext setObject:Antwort2.text forKey:@"hallo2"];
    [savetext setObject:Antwort3.text forKey:@"hallo3"];
    UIButton *buttonPressed = (UIButton *)sender;
    TV *second =[[TV alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    second.buttonTag  = buttonPressed.tag; 
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:second animated:YES];

}
if (buttonTag == 9003) {
    button.tag = 9003;
    NSUserDefaults *savetext = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [savetext setObject:Antwort.text forKey:@"hallo"];
    [savetext setObject:Antwort2.text forKey:@"hallo2"];
    [savetext setObject:Antwort3.text forKey:@"hallo3"];
    UIButton *buttonPressed = (UIButton *)sender;
    TV *second =[[TV alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    second.buttonTag  = buttonPressed.tag; 
[self.navigationController pushViewController:second animated:YES];

}
```

}

Comment: Can you give a more complete code sample? i.e. maybe the entire function containing the code above? I would not suggest saving the data to NSUserDefaults by the way.

Comment: Well I do it, because this way it is saved, when the user closes app and starts it again (It is necessary to maintan the data he entered). I edited it.

Comment: I probably wouldnt be able to decipher the issue without seeing more code. I would suggest taking a look at the buttonTag variable. If it doesnt equal 9001,9002,9003 when the tableview data gets reloaded then it wont show any data.

Comment: Well thats the weird thing, it definitely does, I assure you.

Comment: If thats true then self.userData could be nil or the objects in the collection could be empty.

Comment: Are you sure the the datasource is not nil when you switchback to this table view? 

easy way to check would be to see if breakpoints in the tableview's data source methods (cellForRow etc) are hit when switching back.

Comment: I did and the breakpoints hit.

Answer (score 1):

If the data is read & saved in NSUSerDefaults, try

```
[savetext synchronize]
```

before pushing to new view.